# get output after batch processing in mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I'm running one batch triggered by listener using postman. After batch processing i'm expecting some json response in the postman. tried to set the json in on-complete phase but getting some encrypted or collection data in the response. how can i send my own defined output to end user.

expected output:

{
"status": "completed"
}

[image]

Comment: Can you post your flow's XML? Sounds like you are trying to set the payload in the on complete phase, which you can't do. Read the docs here https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-processing-concept#on-complete.  This isn't encrypted data, rather its an `application/java` payload; an instance of the `BatchJobResult`. From the docs: `...the results of batch processing do not feed back into the flow which may have triggered it, nor do the results return as a response to a caller. Any event source that feeds data into a batch job must be one-way, not request-response.`

Answer (score 0):

You can't return if the batch completed, because it will be executed asynchronously with respect to the caller flow.

What you can do is to decouple the status query from the execution. You can do that for example by updating the status in some persistent place, for example a database, when the batch completes. Then have a second HTTP Listener to check for the status can query that status and return immediately.